# How to separate one page app

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs

I have a one-page app written in React, and I start to feel that the JS is a little bit slow to load. I am thinking about putting some work into my server and also don't send the JS code when it is not necessary. However, as been bundled by Webpack, the javascript file is a whole. What are the good ways to separate a one-page app into parts that dedicated to sub-functions? Or overall what is a good way to improve one-page app performance?

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

Comment: seeing some code would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Code minification](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production-build/#minification) is a common technique to reduce bundle size.
2. [Tree-shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) can also greatly reduce bundle size by removing unused pieces of code.
3. [Codesplitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) (like @FelixKling suggested) is a way to break the bundle up into smaller chunks and pull them in as needed, which can also improve performance, and is supported out-of-the-box by webpack 2.
4. A [vendor bundle](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-libraries/) (which is essentially the same idea a codesplitting) is also a simple way to improve performance as the bother bundles can be downloaded in parallel.
5. [Server-side rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom-server.html) can make the initial load a bit quicker.

Comment: I will definitely try those! Thanks. And which version number does Webpack 2 start with?

Comment: As a guess, 2.0.0